# Error: the transition has been superseded by a different transition

Tags: angularjs, websocket, angular-ui-router

I am get the error, but only sometimes:

```
The transition has been superseded by a different transition
```

I am using `angular V1.6.9` and `ui-router V1.0.16`

Here is my code:

```
var ws = new websocket("ws:/*********")
ws.onmessage = function(message)
{
  if(message)
  {
    if(message.type=="weather")
    {
      $state.go("Index.weather",{weatherObj:message});
    }
    if(message.type=="temperature")
    {
      $state.go("Index.temperature",{tempObj:message});
    }
    if(message.type=="humidity")
    {
      $state.go("Index.humidity",{humObj:message});
    }
    if(message.type=="rain")
    {
      $state.go("Index.rain",{rainObj:message});
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please include the whole stack trace for the error.

Comment: transitionRejection(type: 2, message: The transition has been superseded by a different transition, detail:

Answer (score 1):

I met this error too, and i find a solution, you should use

```
$timeout(() => {
  $state.go('Index.weather')
})
```

this is the way directive `ui-sref` do in the background, and it works fine.